# Create hive table with partitions from a Scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I need a way to create a hive table from a Scala dataframe. The hive table should have underlying files in ORC format in S3 location partitioned by date.

Here is what I have got so far:

I write the scala dataframe to S3 in ORC format

```
df.write.format("orc").partitionBy("date").save("S3Location)
```

I can see the ORC files in the S3 location.
I create a hive table on the top of these ORC files now:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE "tableName"(columnName string)
PARTITIONED BY (date string)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION "S3Location"
TBLPROPERTIES("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")
```

But the hive table is empty, i.e.
`spark.sql("select * from db.tableName")` prints no results.

However, when I remove `PARTITIONED BY` line:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE "tableName"(columnName string, date string)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION "S3Location"
TBLPROPERTIES("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")
```

I see results from the select query.

It seems that hive does not recognize the partitions created by spark. I am using Spark 2.2.0.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Update:**

I am starting with a spark dataframe and I just need a way to create a hive table on the top of this(underlying files being in ORC format in S3 location).

Answer (score 1):

I think the partitions are not added yet to the hive metastore, so u need only to run this hive command :

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name
```

If does not work, may be you need to check these points :

- After writing data into s3, folder should be like : `s3://anypathyouwant/mytablefolder/transaction_date=2020-10-30`
- when creating external table, the location should point to `s3://anypathyouwant/mytablefolder`

And yes, Spark writes data into s3 but does not add the partitions definitions into the hive metastore ! And hive is not aware of data written unless they are under a recognized partition.
So to check what partitions are in the hive metastore, you can use this hive command :

```
SHOW PARTITIONS tablename
```

In production environment, i do not recommand using the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` for this purpose coz it will be too much time consuming by time. The best way, is to make your code add only the newly created partitions to your metastore through rest api.

Comment: Thanks, the `msck repair` command makes it work but I am not sure of the performance in production. How can we add partition to the metastore in the code(the best way you mentioned)? Please note that I have a single dataframe to be written to s3 and hive table needs to be created from it.

Comment: @ic10503 whats your metastore ? aws Glue ? are you using Hcatalog or somthing similar ?

Comment: I think it's Hive metastore/spark-warehouse. Not sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @ic10503 in your aws console, under aws glue, can you see your table definition ?

Comment: Thanks, I have never used AWS Glue. I use Qubole and I can see the table definition, just that the table is empty as I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: hum, the idea is to send rest queries to your metastore, so you need to find how in the documentation of your used metastore !

Comment: @ic10503 plz consider accepting the answer if it helps the the original problem of the post, so we keep the community active and helpful !